# Jquery testimonial rotator. How can I add next and previous buttons

Tags: jquery

I am using a testimonial rotator plugin, it works well but I would like to add forward and back buttons but I am not sure where to start. Here is all the code i question: [code on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/j4MbH/10/)

Any help appreciated

regards Ash

Comment: Ive noticed theres a function called go to next but I am not sure how to add a link to use that to go to the next slide

Comment: Your fiddle didn't work because you had things in the wrong order, you were trying to use the plugin before you added it to `$.fn`. I fixed the order and pointed your question at the updated fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I put together some listeners inside the loop and after quick testing appears to work! Here's the js Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BLNZ7/

The idea is to give element ids to the "previous" and "next" buttons or links. (no, I'm not too creative with these IDs)

```
<button id="prevId">Prev</button>
<span id="nextId">Next</span>​
```

Then reference them when creating the rotator:

```
$(".testimonialrotator").testimonialrotator({
        settings_slideshowTime:3,
        nextId: "nextId",
        prevId: "prevId"
        });

});
```

The listeners inside the rotator just call gotoNext and reset the "time buffer", and there's a new, similar function, gotoPrev, that I added.

```
        $("#"+o.nextId).on('click', function() {
          gotoNext();
          timebuf = 0;
        });   


        $("#"+o.prevId).on('click', function() {
          gotoPrev();
          timebuf = 0;
        });
```

Comment: Thank you  I changed the span tags surrounding the next to a button aswell and got the solution  I was looking for thank you so much [link]http://jsfiddle.net/AJBweb1986/BLNZ7/1/

Comment: because the fiddle is now set to no wrap head, what do I need to change to get it to work on my site, sorry I'm new to jquery and jsfiddle

Comment: I placed everything between the css styles and body, the single file I was working with is here http://pastebin.com/0dUL3tMu  This is my habit, there are other ways you can organize the script, some recommend placing scripts right before `</body>` so the page shows without waiting for the Javascript. If the regular rotator was working for you in a different place, replacing it with the modified version should still work. Make sure you're adding the ids both in the buttons and the rotator object (where the time setting is).

Comment: I'm getting this error- Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'testimonialrotator' on the local site.

Comment: Might be the order that mu is too short corrected (put the rotator chunk above document.ready) Instead, what I did was add `(jQuery)` at the end of the rotator code (I saw that from the downloaded zip.) Try changing the order, if it still doesn't work I'll need more information, if you can post the source on pastebin like I did, please.

Comment: Most importantly the JavaScript has to be inside `<script type="text/javascript">` tags. Also, I included jQuery, flipped the order (like mu is too short), and changed last line to `</html>` Changes are here: http://pastebin.com/0q75esf2

Comment: Although the page probably loads without `</head>`, it should be there just before `<body>`. I just saw it, sorry about that. Going to sleep soon.

Comment: It's working fine now thank you, must have had it spread over too many includes files. I put all the code in the right order in an includes file testimonials.php and it works thankyou, I think it was a little late last night and I was missing it. thank you again